# Postgresql count data based on group data of another table resulting to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I have two tables that look like this:

```
users
id     name     city           state
1      Bob      Los Angeles    California
2      Susan    Dallas         Texas
3      Joe      Los Angeles    California


activity       
type           user_id
Activation     1
Registration   1
Activation     2
Activation     3
```

I want to count the `number of times the activity of type Activation` has taken place to return a dataset like this:

```
[
  {count: 2, city: 'Los Angeles', state: 'California'},
  {count: 1, city: 'Dallas', state: 'Texas'}
]
```

Here is a query I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, user_id,
(SELECT json_agg(users.*) FROM users WHERE activity.user_id = users.id) as users
FROM activity
WHERE type='Activation'
GROUP BY users.city, users.state, user_id
```

And I get this error:
`error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"`

I'm not sure how to do a count like this grouping data from multiple tables.

This is the latest version of Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a view providing correct data, like:

```
CREATE VIEW activations_on_locations AS
    SELECT count(*), U.city, U.state
    FROM users U
    INNER JOIN activity A
        ON U.id = A.user_id
        AND A.type='Activation'
    GROUP BY U.city, U.state;
```

Against that the JSON query is quite straightforward:

```
SELECT json_agg(AOL) FROM activations_on_locations AOL;
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the desired output:

```
SELECT json_agg(users.*) from (select 
 COUNT(id) count, min(city) city, min(state) state from users, activity
where users.id=activity.user_id group by id, city, state) as users;
```